# Hide part of procedural mesh

Tags: shaders, masking

Is there any way I can hide the part of the eye lid and eye ball meshes marked in red? I manage to hide the eye lids with vertex groups + mask modifier, but this doesn't seem to work for the eye ball. The eye ball is a sphere with this shader setup:

https://maxedge.gumroad.com/l/geonodeseye?layout=profile&recommended_by=library

I wish to be able to see the eye from the front and from the sides, as well as to animate it looking in different directions, and preferably also to be able to open and close the eye lids  but without seeing the entire eye ball. Is this at all possible? Is it possible with a boolean modifier or something? Am still new to blender, would be very thankful for any suggestion :)

Update Thank you @moonboots! The eye can be downloaded here: https://maxedge.gumroad.com/l/geonodeseye?layout=profile&recommended_by=library  although you can download it for free I'm not sure I should share it. It has 3 materials, the sclera, the cornea and the iris. I need to be able to animate the eye: dilate the pupil, change colour and saturation of the eye and the blood vessels etc. Would that work with your method? I tried to delete part of the mesh as suggested, but it nevertheless shows. Am probably too new with Blender to properly understand what I'm doing wrong here:

[image: screen shot of the model, red shows the part I wish to hide]

[image: mesh deleted + render view of deleted mesh][image]

Comment: depending on your material, you could make the material rotate on the surface of the sphere?

Comment: @moonboots I'm not sure I understand, or that I formulated my question well! :) I know how to make the iris move around , pupil dilate etc. The problem is that I only want to see as much of the eye ball as you would on any person you meet, not the entire eye ball inside the head :) Biut the entire eye ball needs to exist because otherwise I don't have the possibility to move the gaze around and animate the eyes. So am trying to figure out how to only make the part of the eye ball visible that is currently in view between the eye lids.

Comment: if the object is copyright free, could you please share it (don't forget to pack the image: File > External Data > Pack Resources)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: My bad you're using Geometry Node and my answer has nothing to do with it, I hope a GN master will know how to do it, it's probably easy

Answer (score 3):

Edit: My solution doesn't fit your needs as you're talking about Geometry Nodes but I leave it here nevertheless...

You could keep only a part of your eyes, create an empty at the center of the (former) sphere and give a *UV Project* modifier to your object with the empty as *Object*. In my case I had to rotate the empty 90° on X to see the iris:

[image]

Now when you rotate the empty it projects the image on the surface of the object:

[image]